# How to configure the size of the kernel ring buffer when the kernel is built?

Tags: android, debugging, logging, linux-kernel, circular-buffer

I'm using `dmesg` as a part of studying the android kernel (v3.10.49).

I edited the line

`#define KLOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL 3` to

`#define KLOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL 7`

in the source code `android/system/core/include/cutils/klog.h`

to acquire all kernel log messages including,

- ERROR_LEVEL
- WARNING_LEVEL
- NOTICE_LEVEL
- INFO_LEVEL
- DEBUG_LEVEL

And I hard-coded `void  klog_set_level(int level)` function in

`android/system/core/libcutils/klog.c` to make sure anyone can't change the `klog_level` from the value ***7***.

But the problem is because the kernel uses a ring buffer, it always partially overwrite by the time I get the root shell necessary to run `dmesg` on the device.

The book I'm referring *Android Internals A Confectioner's Cookbook (Volume I: The Power User's View) With updates for Android M, Preview Release 1 (6/2015) By Jonathan Levin* states that

> *"The size of the kernel ring buffer can be configured when the kernel is built"*

But I could not find a clear path to do it in the book or in the web. Can someone please explain the steps?

Here are the links for the files I edited: [klog.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jb4x8gw1e5lx9b2/klog.h?dl=0), [klog.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kar2iz6wjfvjjkr/klog.c?dl=0)